# plotting a time series in R, cannot change the y axis

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am plotting a time series with R, but I could not specify the range of my y-axis. My time series is mat.mean and mat.mean.gro. My plotting code is here:

```
plot(ts(mat.mean, frequency = 12, start = c(1976, 12)), col = "green")
lines(ts(mat.mean.gro, frequency = 12, start = c(1976, 12)), col = "red")
```

I searched around and tried the most popular solutions, like call

```
axis(2, at=seq(0.4, 2, by=0.4) or modify the code to 
plot(ts(mat.mean, frequency = 12, start = c(1976, 12)), ylim = c(0.4, 2.0), col = "green").
```

The problem is :
Without adding ylim = c(0.4, 2.0), y axis has a range for my example, say 0.5 to 2.0. After I adding ylim = c(0.4, 2.0), the range is still 0.5 to 2.0 for y axis. This range will make part of my second line hidden in the graph because the range is not big enough.

My data is here:

```
> mat.mean[1:40]
[1] 1.297994 1.286905 1.289706 1.269770 1.210151 1.215818 1.234242 1.256248
[9] 1.288646 1.290055 1.307555 1.283057 1.263023 1.241875 1.349666 1.264034
[17] 1.245436 1.195517 1.209489 1.162674 1.140096 1.098699 1.180981 1.169342
[25] 1.164076 1.090923 1.097041 1.058406 1.082420 1.123527 1.133088 1.140946
[33] 1.125114 1.124824 1.216989 1.235034 1.183935 1.138729 1.162152 1.259850

> mat.mean.gro[1:40]
[1] 0.9098570 0.8885065 0.8929195 0.8700836 0.8681064 0.8684159 0.8941261
[8] 0.8452582 0.8595206 0.8562907 0.8555994 0.8806937 0.8646242 0.8206538
[15] 0.7967376 0.7490888 0.7478145 0.7160734 0.7147583 0.6936500 0.6844725
[22] 0.6536702 0.6818063 0.6691483 0.6558918 0.6224261 0.6196077 0.6051392
[29] 0.6181448 0.6427169 0.6556036 0.6653853 0.6698488 0.6684122 0.7074804
[36] 0.7204438 0.6926981 0.6774449 0.6843505 0.7112838
```

Free feel to tell if you have any comments on this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "no use"? Make sure to call the `plot` with `ylim=` first, then call the `lines`. It seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: I mean it does not work. I'll try this.

Comment: I called the plot then line, but it does not work. You mean I need to call the ylim= this parameter first in plot()?

Answer (score 1):

Run the code in this order

```
plot(ts(mat.mean, frequency = 12, start = c(1976, 12)), 
    ylim = c(0.4, 2.0), col = "green")
lines(ts(mat.mean.gro, frequency = 12, start = c(1976, 12)), col = "red")
```

If that still does not work, explain what "does not work" means. Do you get an error? Do you just see the green line? Do you just see the red line? What limits are plotted?

Comment: Hi, thank. I ran the code as you suggested. Without adding ylim = c(0.4, 2.0), y axis has a range for my example, say 0.5 to 2.0. After I adding ylim = c(0.4, 2.0), the range is still 0.5 to 2.0 for y axis. This range will make part of my second line hidden in the graph because the range is not big enough.

Comment: Well, I don't believe that `ylim` would have no effect. But perhaps your sample data isn't representative of the range of your observations. How about setting `ylim=range(range(mat.mean), range(mat.mean.gro))`

Comment: Thank you. I finally figured out what the problem is. Yeah, you are right. My data is not representative, so if I change a little bit of the range, the R does not show the minor change very significantly on the plot. If I make a much bigger change than the plot default range, then the effect is significant. Thanks anyway.